# Strange UIPickerView in IOS7

Tags: objective-c, uipickerview, ios7, xcode5

Started developing to match with `IOS 7` , But I'm clueless about `UIPickerView's` Strange behavior in `IOS 7 (Only in IOS7)`.
[As they specified here](http://ios7.io/posts/2889-uipickerview-custom-view-in-uiactionsheet-act-strange-in-ios-7-stack-overflow)
I am also facing an issue. When I click on pickerView , Keypad is getting opened. And I am not able to resign that.

**I tried all following things**

```
[sender resignFirstResponder];
[self dismissKeyboard];
[self.view endEditing:YES];
```

My Code:

```
- (IBAction)selectCountry:(UIControl *)sender {

    UITextField *txtfld = (UITextField*)sender;
    NSLog(@"selectCountry Picker Called:%d ",txtfld.tag);

    [self dismissKeyboard];
    [self.view endEditing:YES];

    [sender resignFirstResponder];

        ActionStringDoneBlock done = ^(ActionSheetStringPicker *picker, NSInteger selectedIndex, id selectedValue) {
            if ([billingCountry respondsToSelector:@selector(setText:)]) {
                [billingCountry performSelector:@selector(setText:) withObject:selectedValue];
                selectedBillingCountry = selectedValue;

                        }

            [self resetShippingServicesControl];
            [self resetProvinceState];
            [self loadViewAsperCountry];
                               };


        ActionStringCancelBlock cancel = ^(ActionSheetStringPicker *picker) {
            NSLog(@"selectCountry Picker Cancelled");
            [self dismissKeyboard];
            [self.view endEditing:YES];
            [sender resignFirstResponder];
        };
        NSArray *countryA = [NSArray arrayWithArray:[self getCountryList]];
        [ActionSheetStringPicker showPickerWithTitle:@"Select Country" rows:countryA initialSelection:0 doneBlock:done cancelBlock:cancel origin:sender];


}
```

But still , Its :( . Kindly help me to figure out solution for this. 
Do I need to Redesign for `IOS7` users ? 
Thanks in advance Geeks.

Comment: I'm using `UIPickerView` with iOS 7, and I don't see any problem...
Maybe it comes from this 3rd party `ActionSheetPicker` you're using ?

Comment: Yes I am using this a component ( 3rd Party) which is available in "https://github.com/TimCinel/ActionSheetPicker/blob/master/Pickers/". Im unable to fine reason for this!!!

Answer (score 0):

Your problems seems to be about `UIActionSheet`, and not `UIPickerView`.

You shouldn't add subviews to a `UIActionSheet`, as stated in [its documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIActionSheet_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

> UIActionSheet is not designed to be subclassed, nor should you add
>   views to its hierarchy. If you need to present a sheet with more
>   customization than provided by the UIActionSheet API, you can create
>   your own and present it modally with
>   presentViewController:animated:completion:.

Comment: Yes I am using this aa a component ( 3rd Party) which is available in "github.com/TimCinel/ActionSheetPicker/blob/master/Pickers/";. Im unable to find reason vinzzz!!

Comment: So do we simply create the UIPickerView and present it modally?